# SSIS package execution using DTExec throwing error "set" is not valid

Tags: sql-server-2014

Kindly help where i am doing wrong,

```
E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn>DTExec /F "D:\SSIS\Import\connection_manager.dtsx" /set "\Package.Variables[User::packagedir].Properties[Value]";"D:\SSIS\Import\\" /set "\Package.Variables[User::PRODDB_connectionstring].Properties[Value]";"Data Source=*********;Initial Catalog=PRODDB;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS;" > "C:\Users\PROD\Desktop\SSIS\log.txt"
```

Getting Following Error :

> Argument
>   ""\Package.Variables[User::PRODDB_connectionstring].Properties[Value];Data
>   Source=*********;Initial
>   Catalog=PRODDB;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto
>   Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS;"" for option "set" is not
>   valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encapsulate your strings with `\` before string start. And then you should just write `.Value` after your parameters instead.

```
    @ECHO OFF
ECHO.
ECHO This is a batch file
ECHO.

DTEXEC.EXE /F "C:\Users\thoje\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Integration Services Project8\Integration Services Project8\Package30.dtsx" /set \Package.Variables[User::packagedir].Value;\""D:\SSIS\Import\\"\" /set \Package.Variables[User::conn].Value;\""Data Source=EGC25199;Initial Catalog=LegOgSpass;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False"\"
PAUSE
CLS
```